# Serializing functions/classes in python

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, pickle, dill

I don't know how to serialize.  From surfing, I came to know that dill can serialize functions and classes. I have an example below where there are two classes and each class has some functions with different parameters. I want to serialize them all together. Can someone help me into this

```
class dummy_class_1:
   def dummy_func_1(self,master):
    ..

   def dummy_func_2(self):
    ...

class dummy_class_2:
    def dummy_func_3(self,event):
    ...

    def dummy_func_4(self):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to serialize the classes together, then you can just `dump` them to a string:

```
>>> class dummy_class_1(object):
...   def dummy_func_1(self, master):
...     return
...   def dummy_func_2(self):
...     return
... 
>>> class dummy_class_2(object):
...   def dummy_func_3(self, event):
...     return
...   def dummy_func_4(self):
...     return
... 
>>> import dill
>>>          
>>> dill.dumps((dummy_class_1, dummy_class_2))
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01U\x08TypeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04U\rdummy_class_1q\x05h\x01U\nObjectTypeq\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08\x85q\t}q\n(U\n__module__q\x0bU\x08__main__q\x0cU\x0cdummy_func_1q\rcdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x0e(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\x0fUpc\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x04\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00selft\x06\x00\x00\x00master(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x0c\x00\x00\x00dummy_func_1\x02\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q\x10\x85q\x11Rq\x12c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\rNN}q\x13tq\x14Rq\x15U\x0cdummy_func_2q\x16h\x0e(h\x0fUec\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x04\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00self(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x0c\x00\x00\x00dummy_func_2\x04\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q\x17\x85q\x18Rq\x19c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x16NN}q\x1atq\x1bRq\x1cU\x07__doc__q\x1dNutq\x1eRq\x1fh\x00(h\x04U\rdummy_class_2q h\x08\x85q!}q"(h\x0bh\x0cU\x0cdummy_func_3q#h\x0e(h\x0fUoc\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x04\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00selft\x05\x00\x00\x00event(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x0c\x00\x00\x00dummy_func_3\x02\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q$\x85q%Rq&c__builtin__\n__main__\nh#NN}q\'tq(Rq)U\x0cdummy_func_4q*h\x0e(h\x0fUec\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x04\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00self(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x0c\x00\x00\x00dummy_func_4\x04\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q+\x85q,Rq-c__builtin__\n__main__\nh*NN}q.tq/Rq0h\x1dNutq1Rq2\x86q3.'
```

Or, you can `dump` them to a file...

```
>>> with open('dummy.pkl', 'wb') as f:
...   dill.dump(dummy_class_1, f)
...   dill.dump(dummy_class_2, f)
... 
>>>
```

Then when you restart, you can `load` them:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep  2 2015, 17:36:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> with open('dummy.pkl', 'rb') as f:
...   dummy_class_1 = dill.load(f)
...   dummy_class_2 = dill.load(f)
... 
>>> print dill.source.getsource(dummy_class_1)
class dummy_class_1(object):
  def dummy_func_1(self, master):
    return
  def dummy_func_2(self):
    return

>>>
```

The class methods (i.e. the functions inside the classes) will just get serialized within the classes.

Note that I used python 2.7 in my response, but it works exactly the same for python 3.x.

Comment: Thanks! I am basically working on developing the GUI (tkinter) using python, where I was thinking the save button should save the state of GUI and once loaded, it should load the GUI back from that state.
Do you think that serializing the classes would help

Comment: It depends.  Some class instances are harder to serialize than others, but they should generally work if the classes are imported from another file and pickled by reference.

Comment: how can we pickled by reference... i am a newbie

Comment: if you use `pickle`, it will pickle a class by reference.  If you use `dill`, you have to set `byref=True`, either globally with `dill.settings['byref'] = True` or per-call with `dill.dump(object_to_pickle, byref=True)`

Comment: Thanks!! By doing this, i am still not able to save the current state of GUI. Do i have to  dump the widgets too?

Comment: You have to dump everything that contains state.

Comment: it will be very helpful, if u could show me an example

Comment: I can't show you an example, as I don't know what widgets you are using… but essentially, anything that saves state (in an attribute), you will have to serialize as in my answer above (in the `with` statement).